# No value get returned from php to android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I've have tried many method from Stack Overflow on how to retrieve the `php` value to android app but no success. I have no idea what's wrong here. Can someone figure out the problem for me? or at least a link/ hint ?

Firstly, I'm call   `addInformation(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]);` //to insert the data into **MySQL** through php.

Then `showList ()`; // show the lastID from php

Finally  display it `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"aa"+lastID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

```
    addInformation(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]);
    showList();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lastID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**I declared the lastID as global.**

This is my addInformation function

```
  public void addInformation(final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut) {
        class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME, name);
                data.put(Config.KEY_WEATHER, weather);
                data.put(Config.KEY_DATE, date2);
                data.put(Config.KEY_STATUS, status);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEIN, timeIn);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT, timeOut);
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_INFORMATION, data);
                return result;
            }
        }
        AddInfo ru = new AddInfo();
        ru.execute(name, weather, date2, status, timeIn, timeOut);
    }
```

**addInformation.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('dbConnect.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $response = array();

        //Getting values

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $weather = $_POST['weather'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $timeIn = $_POST['timeIn'];
        $timeOut = $_POST['timeOut'];


        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO information(name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('$name','$weather','$date', '$status', '$timeIn', '$timeOut')";

        //Importing our db connection script
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Information Added Successfully';
            $insertId= mysqli_insert_id($con);
            $response["lastId"]=$insertId;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Information';
        }

        //Closing the database 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>     // I get Information Added Successfully follow by the latest ID
```

Next, go to `showList()` to get the `latestID`  **by using the same php script**.

```
  public void showList() {
        class GetLastID extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WorkDetailsTable.this);
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                        GetLastID.this.cancel(true);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String url_select = "http://192.168.107.115/Android/CRUD/addInformation.php"; // same php in addInformation, get the latestID and return to android app

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                try {
                    // Set up HTTP post

                    // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    // Read content & Log
                    inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
                    //e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
                    // e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
                    // e3.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e4) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //  Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
                    //e4.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Convert response to string using String Builder
                try {
                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    result = sBuilder.toString();
                    JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    lastID = resultObject.getString("lastId"); // get the latestID from php
                    Log.e("TAG",lastID);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "A");
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

I suppose the Toast will display the latest ID, but it display null instead.

**Edited**

addInformation()

```
   @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                showList();
```

showList()

```
  public void showList() {
        class GetLastID extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WorkDetailsTable.this);
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";
            ProgressDialog loading;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                        GetLastID.this.cancel(true);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"aa"+lastID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update php code

```
//Executing query to database
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    // echo 'Information Added Successfully'; // Remove this line
    $insertId= mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $response["lastId"]=$insertId;
    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    echo 'Could Not Add Information';
}
```

And use this class

```
public class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContentValues> {

private final Context context;
private final ProgressDialog loading;

public AddInfo(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

private ContentValues handleActionSend(String name, String weather, String date2, String status, String timeIn, String timeOut) {
    ContentValues retour = new ContentValues();
    retour.put("success", false);

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Config.ADD_INFORMATION);
        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Config.KEY_USER_NAME, name));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Config.KEY_WEATHER, weather));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Config.KEY_DATE, date2));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Config.KEY_STATUS, status));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Config.KEY_TIMEIN, timeIn));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT, timeOut));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.toString());

        retour.put("success", true);
        retour.put("lastId", json.getInt("lastId"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        retour.put("message", "MalformedURLException Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        retour.put("message", "UnsupportedEncodingException Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        retour.put("message", "IOException Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        retour.put("message", "Exception Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return retour;
}


@Override
protected ContentValues doInBackground(String... args) {
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
    return handleActionSend(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ContentValues contentValues) {
    super.onPostExecute(contentValues);
    loading.dismiss();
    String message;
    if(contentValues.getAsBoolean("success")) {
        message = "Inserted successfully: "+ contentValues.getAsInt("lastId");
    } else {
        message = "An error has occured!\n"+ contentValues.getAsString("message");
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

And call it

```
public void addInformation(final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut) {
    AddInfo ru = new AddInfo(this);
    ru.execute(name, weather, date2, status, timeIn, timeOut);
}
```

Comment: `contentValues.getAsInt("lastId");` is the lastId from php ?

Comment: Yes got from here `retour.put("lastId", json.getInt("lastId"));`. json contains the return of php code. First we get that value and put it in the result of the task which is a content value.

Comment: `Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 31014
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)`

Comment: It is caused by the ProgressDialog. You can remove it and try using a toast instead or declare AddInfo class as internal to your activity and show progress dialog while loading and hide it after job done.

Comment: I get An Error has occured Excertion error : No value for success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99839/discussion-between-john-joe-and-henboy331).

Comment: hi,do you know what's wrong here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690235/total-hours-cannot-be-inserted-into-mysql-from-android

Answer (score 1):

You probably have json exceptions in your logcat, in your php you have:

```
    //Executing query to database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Information Added Successfully';
        $insertId= mysqli_insert_id($con);
        $response["lastId"]=$insertId;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Add Information';
    }
```

so you `echo` no json strings like 'Information Added Successfully' - your json parser will fail on it and throw exception. You should only return what json_encode returns. If you have errors in your php script (like wrong input data, etc.), then put them into json also.

Comment: How can I return it to android variable(lastID) ?

Comment: for example: `echo json_encode(array('lastId'=>$insertId));`. But your current json code in php is OK, the problem is that you should not return anything else. Put a Toast in place of `Log.e("TAG", "A");` , it should show indicating exception in parsing you json.

Comment: @JohnJoe there might be other problems in your code, ie. you should not show Toast-s in your doInBackground, do it inside onPostExecute - all your UI updates do inside onPostExecute. You can change GUI only from UI thread, onPostExecute is executed on UI thread, while doInBackground is executed on worker thread.

Comment: A little bit confused here. Inside showList don't have onPostExecute

Comment: @JohnJoe onPostExecute is a method from AsyncTask, you should override it inside your GetLastID class.

Comment: `Inside showList don't have onPostExecute`. Indeed. But then add it to the AsyncTask in showList()  as you need it to display that Toast().