# convert textView to string

Tags: java, android, string, textview

```
TextView totalHours;
String TotalHours;
totalHours.setText(("Total hours : " + hours + ":" + minutes));
```

Assume the output is **Totalhours :13:25**

Now I want to convert the totalHours into `String` and save 13:25 into MySQL.

```
 TotalHours=totalHours.getText().toString();
 String[] time= TotalHours.split(":", 2);
 addInformation(time[1]);
```

Is this the correct way to convert a `textView` into `String` ?

Comment: Why you are trying this long way get text and than split it? You simply can get the hours value.

Comment: Why don't you just use `hours + ":" + minutes` instead of trying to pull it from the TextView?

Comment: @MikeM. If this is the correct way, why I will get error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690235/total-hours-cannot-be-inserted-into-mysql-from-android

Comment: @MikeM. No stack trace, only display this error

Comment: @MikeM. Data type I put 'TIME'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best you can directly store your variable  hours ,minutes with String conversion.

```
  hours.toString();
```

or

```
String.valueOf(hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the correct way. Getting text from a TextView returns CharSequence. To convert CharSequence to String, toString() function is used.

Or you can directly store time in one string variable and insert it into MySql database.

Comment: I get error .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690235/total-hours-cannot-be-inserted-into-mysql-from-android

Answer (score 0):

```
TotalHours=totalHours.getText().toString();
String[] time= TotalHours.split(":");
String result= time[1]+time[2];
addInformation(result);
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I tried with this:

```
String.valueOf(totalHours.getText());
```

If the first answer don't work for you, maybe this will help.